# Small Linux distro with GRUB2 as its boot loader?

Tags: boot-loader, small-distribution

I usually install GRUB2 on its own partition.  This is because I consider all my OSs to be peers.  No one of them should own the boot loader.  Any one OS can be removed and the others would still boot.

Now I've decided to take it a step further.  I want to install a small (maybe even text mode only) OS to act as the system bootloader and maintenance utility.  So that small distro is kind of like the traffic cop for the "real" OSs.

So I need a small but stable release that can have GRUB2 as its boot loader that runs on UEFI systems preferably 64-bit.  (SliTAZ doesn't support UEFI, I can't find any info about TinyCore using GRUB2, nor Puppy, I'd prefer not LUbuntu b/c I mainly use Debian and I want to hedge my bet against any hypothetical Debian issue.)

Comment: Does it have to be GRUB?  Could you go real simple and just use systemd-boot for what you want to do?

Comment: Thx for bringing  systemd-boot to my attention.  I hadn't given Gummiboot a thought in years.  Now I know what became of it.  Well I think GRUB2 is the more conventional and better known, but if systemd does the job, then I guess it's fine.